# There is an error but getting statuscode of 200

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

[image]

```js
    const request = https.request(url, options, function(response){
        if (response.statusCode === 200){
            res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html")
        } else {
            res.sendFile(__dirname+"/failure.html")
        }
        response.on("data", function(data){
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        })
    })
    request.write(jsonData);
    request.end();
});
```

the console shows error but the status Code response on node.js is 200 I don't know how

Comment: looks like the api is returning errors under a 200 -- frustrating, but not uncommon. (maybe the operation succeeded, but with errors.) you may not be able to use the status code as a reliable proxy for success

Comment: Also check the "error_code" in you conditional statement!